# Why am I getting "The object is in a detached or deleted state" when deleting an unmodified row?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework 4 to manage my data in a simple grid. It is something we needed to just keep track of a checkbox in a table. It was intended to be a quick fix to get data in/out from a little table, not a  big project.

I have the following defined in my form

```
private MyDBEntites _context = new MyDBEntities(...);
private BindingSource myBindingSource = new BindingSource(...);
public DataGridView myGrid = new DataGridView();
```

In my constructor, I populate the grid

```
    int customerID = 1234;

    myGrid.DataSource = myBindingSource;

    myBindingSource.DataSource = (from cc In _context.myRecords
                                  where cc.CustomerID = customerID
                                  select cc).AsEnumerable();
```

My intent is to then modify the table as-needed. When I'm finished making changes, I click a button that calls SaveForm()

```
public void SaveForm()
{
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

For adding and modifying rows, this works very well. However, when I delete a row, then call SaveChanges, above, my application crashes with "The object is in a detached or deleted state". This is even true when I've done absolutely nothing except delete a row.

Why can't I delete a row in this way? Does anyone know what might be getting "changed" before deletion? If so, do you know how I can work around this?

**UPDATE**

I still don't know WHY it is failing, but I do have a work-around. I was trying to queue-up the deletes and manage all of my changes with one "SaveChanges()" call. There was no business need for this. Just a personal preference. Instead, I've put a SaveChanges at the end of the Remove, and that is working perfectly.

```
private void myGrid_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row == null) 
    {
        return;
    }

    if ((MessageBox.Show("Are you certain that you want to delete this entry?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)) 
    {
        myRecord req = (myRecord)e.Row.DataBoundItem;

        myBindingSource.Remove(req);
        _context.myRecords.DeleteObject(req);

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but are you removing the row from whatever backing data model you're using to render your grid? It could be that the error is occuring when the grid tries to render the deleted object.

Comment: Interesting thought. I didn't think so. To test this, I modified the code to handle deletions manually. I delete it from the binding source, then delete the object from `_context`. I get the same error when I save. I don't think this is the root issue.

Comment: Entity Framework does not work well when Binding Grids.  From my experience, other controls work well - but not grids.  And I have done a lot of them.

What I have had to do with Telerik and Infragistics (not tried the built in Microsoft Grid) is to control the adding and removing of rows to the grids.

If there are related (FK relationships) entities, simply picking something from a DropDown to a column in the grid will add the entity to the context.  If you wanted to cancel the edit on the row, you need to remove it manually.

I think you are handling this correctly IMHO.